# Ansible: Failed to connect to the host via ssh

Tags: ssh, ansible

I created a SSH key-pair using the following command:
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "remote-user" -b 4096`

I saved the key pair inside `~/.ssh` directory of my local computer:

```
-rw-------   1 steve.rogers  INTRA\users  3381 Jan 18 16:52 remote-user
-rw-------   1 steve.rogers  INTRA\users   742 Jan 18 16:52 remote-user.pub
```

I have an instance in GCP and I have added the above public_key for the user `remote_user` to it.

After that I tried to SSH into the instance using the following command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/remote-user remote-user@<gcp-instance-ip>
```

I was successfully able to ssh into the machine.

After that I tried to execute my playbook:

```
ansible-playbook setup.yaml --tags "mytag" --extra-vars "env=stg" -i /environments/stg/hosts
```

The execution did not succeed and ended up with the following error:

```
<gcp-server102> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<gcp-server102> SSH: EXEC ssh -o ControlPersist=15m -F ssh.config -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/steve.rogers/.ansible/cp/7be59d33ab gcp-server102 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
Read vars_file './environments/{{env}}/group_vars/all.yaml'
<gcp-server101> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<gcp-server101> SSH: EXEC ssh -o ControlPersist=15m -F ssh.config -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/steve.rogers/.ansible/cp/6a68673873 gcp-server101 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
Read vars_file './environments/{{env}}/group_vars/all.yaml'
<gcp-server201> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<gcp-server201> SSH: EXEC ssh -o ControlPersist=15m -F ssh.config -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/steve.rogers/.ansible/cp/e330878269 gcp-server201 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<gcp-server202> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<gcp-server202> SSH: EXEC ssh -o ControlPersist=15m -F ssh.config -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/steve.rogers/.ansible/cp/6f7ebc0471 gcp-server202 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<gcp-server102> (255, b'', b'remote-user@<gcp-instance-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n')
<gcp-server101> (255, b'', b'remote-user@<gcp-instance-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n')
fatal: [gcp-server102]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: remote-user@<gcp-instance-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}
fatal: [gcp-server101]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: remote-user@<gcp-instance-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}
<gcp-server202> (255, b'', b'remote-user@<gcp-instance-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n')
<gcp-server201> (255, b'', b'remote-user@<gcp-instance-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n')
fatal: [gcp-server202]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: remote-user@<gcp-instance-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}
fatal: [gcp-server201]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: remote-user@<gcp-instance-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I sshed into the `gcp_instance` and checked the `authorized_keys` file and it contains the correct `public_key` for the `remote_user`.

These are my `ssh.config`, `ansible.cfg` and `host` files:

**ssh.config:**

```
Host bastion-host
    User                   remote-user
    HostName               <gcp-instance-ip>
    ProxyCommand           none
    IdentityFile           ~/.ssh/remote-user
    BatchMode              yes
    PasswordAuthentication no

Host gcp-server*
    ServerAliveInterval    60
    TCPKeepAlive           yes
    ProxyCommand           ssh -q -A remote-user@<gcp-instance-ip> nc %h %p
    ControlMaster          auto
    ControlPersist         8h
    User                   remote-user
    IdentityFile           ~/.ssh/remote-user
```

**ansible.cfg:**

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlPersist=15m -F ssh.config -q
scp_if_ssh = True
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
```

**host**

```
[gcp_instance]
gcp_instance01

[gcp_instance:children]
gcp_instance_level_01
gcp_instance_level_02

[gcp_instance_level_01]
gcp-server102
gcp-server101

[gcp_instance_level_02]
gcp-server201
gcp-server202
```

What could be the issue that is preventing my playbook from executing?

Comment: The error crops up when Ansible tries to connect to `remote-user@<gcp-instance-ip>`, but there is no entry for `<gcp-instance-ip>` in your `ssh.config` file, so `ssh` doesn't know to use the appropriate private key file. You need to get things configured so that `ssh -F ssh.config remote-user@<gcp-instance-ip>` works correctly.

Comment: @larsks I have an entry for `<gcp-instance-ip>` in my `ssh.config` under `Host bastion-host`.

Comment: Is `bastion-host` actually an ip address in your config file? It's not here in your question, so the obvious answer is the one I posted in my previous comment. If that's the case, please update your question so that the values you show in your config file match the values you show on your command line...and, of course, verify that the `ssh` command line I suggested works correctly.